# Name of Entitiy Framework Database Server From Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The app.Config file is as follows:-

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="v11.0" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

When I create a program which queries my non-existant database, entity framework should automatically generate a database, given my context name. When I run the program, no errors show, yet I cannot see my database in the server explorer menu.

I was wondering if you could advise me if I have to change any settings to view this database? Apparently entity creates the DB in a localdb location. Any directions would be much appreciated.

Comment: There should be another section, <connectionStrings>. That is the configuration that tells entity framework where to create/read the database. Can you post that section as well?

Comment: Apparently I don't need the connection string section, as the defaultConnectionFactory handles that for me? At least that's what the tutorial is telling me...

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do all the time:

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add name="MyApplicationName" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
           AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\databasename.mdf;
           Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And, in my dbcontext file, I use this:

```
 public myDbContext() : base("MyApplicationName") { }
```

In this scenario, please do not forget to create App_Data folder in your application.